# grok{} filter to split based on a delimiter comma

Tags: split, logstash, grok

A line in log file is as follows,

```
"10 Sep 2014 07:16:33 , INFO  , REST , xxx-xxxx-xxx1-yyyy , classname , [  <<MyClass>> Start -> mymessage #######]"
```

I want to split the entire line with **comma** as delimiter.

ie)

```
Date = 10 Sep 2014 07:16:33
level = INFO  
Layer = REST
Txid = xxx-xxxx-xxx1-yyyy
classname = classname
message = [  <<MyClass>> Start -> mymessage #######]
```

How should I write my grok filter for this?

Comment: Have you seen the csv{} filter?

Answer (score 0):

Add a pattern

```
COMMA_DELIMITER %{SPACE},%{SPACE}
```

And the filter is as follows:

```
filter {
   grok {
      patterns_dir => "/root/mypatterns"
      match => ["message", "%{DATESTAMP:LOG_DATE}%{COMMA_DELIMITER}%{LOGLEVEL:LEVEL}%{COMMA_DELIMITER}%{WORD:LAYER}%{COMMA_DELIMITER}%{UUID:txid}%{COMMA_DELIMITER}%{WORD:classname}%{COMMA_DELIMITER}%{GREEDYDATA:filtered_message}"]
   }

  date {
     match => ["LOG_DATE", "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"]
  }
}
```